# Getting Not Authorized error from twitcurl timelineUserGet method

Tags: c++, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm currently playing with C++ on Linux and Twitter using twitcurl. I've built twitcurl, and it seems to work generally, I've been able to tweet from a slightly customised version of the twitterClient sample from their project. However, I've been struggling to read user's timelines.

Now, I know general authentication is working as I manage to tweet as the correct user first.

However, when I try to read user timelines using the below code:

```
/* Get user timeline */
replyMsg = "";
printf( "\nGetting user timeline\n" );
if( twitterObj.timelineUserGet( true, false, 5 ) )
{
    twitterObj.getLastWebResponse( replyMsg );
    printf( "\ntwitterClient:: twitCurl::timelineUserGet web response:\n%s\n", replyMsg.c_str() );
}
else
{
    twitterObj.getLastCurlError( replyMsg );
    printf( "\ntwitterClient:: twitCurl::timelineUserGet error:\n%s\n", replyMsg.c_str() );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
twitterClient:: twitCurl::timelineUserGet web response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hash><request>/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?     count=5?trim_user=1</request><error>Not authorized</error></hash>
```

I'm unsure whether this is related to the invalid url twitcurl generates with multiple ? symbols which might conflict with authentication.

The full source code can be found at https://github.com/paulspencerwilliams/CPlusPlusSocialPlayground/blob/master/twitterClient.cpp .

Answer (score 1):

[The following post helped me to solve the same problem](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/issues/detail?id=38)

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> Sending certain characters to twitter API (Any character that has to be percent encoding, except the blank space?).
>
> **What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
>
> I'd expect
>   twitter's server to accept my oauth signature but it hits me in the
>   face instead.
>
> **What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
>
> r88, this problem applies to both linux and wii (through devkitpro)
>
> **Please provide any additional information below.**
>
> The problem can be fixed by removing the urlencode() calls within buildOAuthRawDataKeyValPairs() in oauth.cpp.
>
> That is according to [how twitter says we have to do it](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature). I don't know (did not check) if that's how the oauth spec says it should be done but it is clearly how it works with twitter.
>
> Did you write oauthlib.cpp?

Comment: you should post some of the content in the link.  If the link evers fails, then this will not be helpful to other users.

Comment: @bluefeet He actually did, the content of his post is the actual solution of the link.

Comment: @ForceMagic my point is that the entire content of the link should be posted here, in the event the link fails there is nothing to reference.